# jQuery Mouse Enter Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('section').mouseenter(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a').removeClass('colorAdded');
        $("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass('colorAdded');
    });
});
```

For some reason, the **`mouseenter`** function does not seem to be working. When the mouse scrolls over one of the sections (which have the section tag), the corresponding link (which have the a tag) in the top right corner should gain a green background color. However, it is unresponsive.

Comment: if you do this $('a').removeClass('color'); then it will remove class from all achor tag

Comment: It looks to me, in the codepen, that you haven't included the jQuery library.

Comment: @AndyG Yes he did

Comment: You are also using some inline styles for background-color, which will take precedence over values set in a stylesheet.

Comment: @Epitouille ... he did now.

Comment: @AndyG Ah ok, he did that very fast then :)

Comment: I added it because I saw it was missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('section').mouseenter(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('a').removeClass('colorAdded');
        $("a[href='#"+id+"']").addClass('colorAdded');
    });
});
```

It was an issue with not including quotations in selecting the `a` tag with the `href` targeting.

Comment: JQuery is added: check "settings > Javascript" in the codepen

Comment: I've updated my answer. The library wasn't included when this was first posted.

Comment: @Everett You should not update your question with the answer. Instead you should mark this answer as correct. (I reversed your change in the question)

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually don't know why your codepen example is not working, I didn't look into your code carefully, but I tried to create simple code like bellow and it worked.
the thing you probably should care about is how you import JQuery into your page.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

hopefully this following codes can help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').mouseenter( function() {
      console.log('hahaha');
    })
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="test">
    <button class="test-button" > test button </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```